# How do I fix the pull to refresh time?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

I am using the following code for pull to refresh :
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

However, I would like to replace the last date and time which displays as eg: 2:30 pm, July 10 to July 10, 2:30 pm. Can anyone point out where this code is residing and what line I can interchange for it to work?

Thanks! Justin

Answer (score 0):

In sample code, In each activity (grid/list etc)eg: **PullToRefreshListActivity.java** there is a method called:

```
mPullRefreshListView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
    String label = DateUtils.formatDateTime(getApplicationContext(),System.currentTimeMillis(),
    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

    // Update the LastUpdatedLabel
    refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setLastUpdatedLabel(label);

    // Do work to refresh the list here.
    new GetDataTask().execute();
}
});
```

The method that updates text is :

```
refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setLastUpdatedLabel(label);
```

and the date is created by the code:

```
String label = DateUtils.formatDateTime(getApplicationContext(),System.currentTimeMillis(),
        DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);
```

Comment: so how do i interchange date and time? do I just need to do this ?String label = DateUtils.formatDateTime(getApplicationContext(),System.currentTimeMillis(),
         DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE |DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME  | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL); it isnt showing any results?